# Need to show that if the number sequence \X_n converges to c, then the sequence \X_n is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

I tried to show that if \X_n is a sequence such that \X_1 < \X_2 < \X_N < ..... and \X_n converges to C that it is an increasing sequence by definition bounded by A and B such that B < \X_n < A for all positive n. Then I supposed \X_n increases without bound. Then I got to \X_n > A but then it was increasing without bound and so B < \X_n and A < \X_n so \X_n is not in (a,b) and thus does not converge.

However my professor says I only considered an increasing sequence and need to resubmit my proof.

Do I need to show that the same would happen for a decreasing sequence?

I don’t know how to directly show that it it is bounded then it has to converge... I can show that it it’s increasing, it’s not bounded, it doesn’t converge and that if it is decreasing, it is not bounded and does not converge.

Comment: Do you think that every sequence is either increasing or decreasing?

Comment: Sequences can be neither increasing nor decreasing. You'll need to use the epsilon-N definition of convergence here

Comment: Well no. You could have a constant sequence as well or one that jumps back and forth. How can I better search this forum for the question? If it’s already been answered maybe I will find what I need to understand there... but I’m obviously doing something wrong searching because I can’t find it